# Typescript Union Type stops distinguishing once a custom class is included in the union

Tags: typescript, union

I have found that the typescript 2.0.3 compiler will compile without complaint an invalid assignment if the union type in question includes a user defined class of any kind.

Example:

```
class Bar {}

// Complains as expected:
interface Foo {
    bar: number|string
}

// Does not complain, surprisingly:
interface Foo2 {
    bar: number|string|Bar
}

var a = <Foo> {
    bar: 5
};
var a2 = <Foo> {
    bar: "yar"
};
//var a3 = <Foo> {
//    bar: new Date() // compiler complains as expected.
//};

var b = <Foo2> {
    bar: new Date() // compiler does not complain, I am confused.
};
```

The compiler error I get when I uncomment `a3` is:

```
lib/src/thing.ts(18,10): error TS2352: Type '{ bar: Date; }' cannot be converted to type 'Foo'.
  Types of property 'bar' are incompatible.
    Type 'Date' is not comparable to type 'string | number'.
      Type 'Date' is not comparable to type 'number'.
```

I would expect to receive the same error when assigning `b`, but it compiles just fine without complaint.

Is this a known issue? Or is this expected behavior and I am not seeing why this should be considered valid? I would like to be able to rely on the union type to ensure that the property is one of several things, including classes I defined myself, so any insights would be most appreciated.

Thanks, in advance!

---

Edit: I did a little more testing and came up with an even simpler example:

```
class Bar {}

var a = <string|number> 4;
var b = <string|number> "thing";
var c = <string|number> new Bar(); // works: confusing
var d = <Bar> 4;                   // ... confusing
var f = <number> new Bar();        // ... also confusing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript is using [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), as [written in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#introduction):

> One of TypeScript’s core principles is that type-checking focuses on
>   the shape that values have. This is sometimes called “duck typing” or
>   “structural subtyping”

Since your `Bar` class is empty, the compiler manages to match the `Date` object with `Bar`, because there are no contradictions.
But once you add a member or method to `Bar` you'll get an error:

```
class Bar {
    x: number;
}

var b = <Foo2> {
    bar: new Date()
};
```

Produces:

```
Type '{ bar: Date; }' cannot be converted to type 'Foo2'.
  Types of property 'bar' are incompatible.
    Type 'Date' is not comparable to type 'string | number | Bar'.
      Type 'Date' is not comparable to type 'Bar'.
        Property 'x' is missing in type 'Date'.
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Bar%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Complains%20as%20expected%3A%0D%0Ainterface%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20number%7Cstring%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Does%20not%20complain%2C%20surprisingly%3A%0D%0Ainterface%20Foo2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20number%7Cstring%7CBar%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20a%20%3D%20%3CFoo%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%205%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Avar%20a2%20%3D%20%3CFoo%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20%22yar%22%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%2F*var%20a3%20%3D%20%3CFoo%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20new%20Date()%20%2F%2F%20compiler%20complains%20as%20expected.%0D%0A%7D%3B*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20b%20%3D%20%3CFoo2%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20new%20Date()%20%2F%2F%20compiler%20does%20not%20complain%2C%20I%20am%20confused.%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A))

Comment: Although technically, duck typing is not really the same as structural typing. Duck typing is more of a run-time phenomenon that only care about the existence of used members, while structural typing is a compile time comparison of types.